# Developer Options disappeared?

Tags: factory-reset, 7.0-nougat, lg, developer-options

Recently I had to factory reset my LG Stylo 3 running Android 7. Now the section in my settings that was "Developer Options" is no longer there. How can I get it back?

Comment: Please [edit] to add Android version in question and tags too. You need to tap *build number* 7 times (usually you will find that in *About Phone*. Have you done that?

Comment: Thank you i have not. i will edit momentarily

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Developer Options" is by default not shown on recent Android versions. To make it show up, you should go to **Settings -> About -> Tap on "Build version" 7 times**, and then it will come back. This action needs to be performed every time the phone is factory-reset, since it's stored as a (hidden) setting item.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment, at best? An evident duplicate doesn't need a fleshed-out answer, but a redirect to the earlier post where the answer is both correct and accepted.